# test method with MultipartFile as a parameter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, powermock

I've got this method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain")
@ResponseBody
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    LOGGER.debug("Attempt to upload file with template.");
    try {
        return FileProcessUtils.processFileUploading(file);
    } catch (UtilityException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to process file.", e.getWrappedException());
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to test it using `junit` and `powermock`.

```
@Test
public void testUploadFile() {
    MultipartFile file = buildMultipartFile();
    mockStatic(FileProcessUtils.class);
    FileProcessUtils.processFileUploading(file);
    expectLastCall().andReturn(FILE_CONTENT);
    replay(FileProcessUtils.class);
    String fileContent = templateSupportRest.uploadFile(file);
    verify(FileProcessUtils.class);
    assertEquals(FILE_CONTENT, fileContent);
}
```

But the problem is that I need somehow to pass as `MultipartFile` object with specific `FILE_CONTENT`. 
To do that I need to build instance of `MultipartFile`.

```
private MultipartFile buildMultipartFile() {
    DiskFileItem diskFileItem = new DiskFileItem("file", "text/plain", true, "file", 100, null);
    MultipartFile file = new CommonsMultipartFile(diskFileItem);
    return file;
}
```

However I've got problems with `DiskFileItem` object. When I create it like this I get `NullPointerException` in `getSize()` method of `DiskFileItem` object.
The constructor of `DiskFileItem` itself has this parameters

```
String fieldName, 
String contentType, 
boolean isFormField, 
String fileName, 
int sizeThresold, 
File repository
```

So the question is - how to instantiate `DiskFileItem` or is there another way to handle the situation?

Comment: Why so complex? Why not simply use a `MockMultipartFile` from Spring Test instead of trying to hack around your libraries. Also mocking static methods imho indicates that there is something wrong in your design.

Comment: You can also use MockMvc to post file contents instead of testing the java layer directly.

Comment: With your current test you don't need a `MultipartFile` you can just pass in `null`. You are mocking everything...

Comment: Oh. Wow. Indeed. I usually do as close as possible to the flow.